# Listening Serial Ports

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, softwareserial, communication

guys. I need your help. I have 6 Serial Channels and I need to listen this channel and be sure which channel is working? How can I do that? Can I listen this channel by using digital inputs? Or Do I have to use a devices which has a 6 Serial ports? Like 2 Arduino Mega?

Comment: Are they TTL UART or true RS-232?

Comment: They are working on RS-232 level. I am going to use RS-232 TTL Converter

Comment: And you don't care about *what* the data is, only if there *is* data?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just need to check is there data

Comment: Possibly a better way to ask the question - is all that is necessary it to see electrical activity on the RS232 Data Receive line?  No matter if it makes sense?  Even if it is noise?   Then the answer might be to use external latching registers and sample the registers using an Arduino. But if we need to make sense of the data, then it may be best to use 6 Arduinos to monitor 6 RS232 serial inputs using the HW UART in each Arduno.  Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

For your needs you don't need actual UARTs. You can do it all with normal GPIO pins and one (or more) interrupts.

UART communication is characterised by having a "start bit" at the beginning of all bytes. That is, in TTL terms, a transition from HIGH to LOW. You just need to look out for that transition.

You could:

- Use Pin Change interrupts on 6 pins to monitor for any FALLING transistion, or
- Use one interrupt pin with a *wired OR* of all the signals along with individual pins for each signal to determine which triggered the interrupt.

To determine "is it active" you just need to know that an interrupt has occurred and which pin triggered it, and has that been seen within a certain time period (to be decided by you).